# Stable alternative to collect_into - or - how do I collect a sized queue?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have some pipeline which manipulates an iterator to a very big data set, and at the end, I wish to just keep the N top values.

I wrote a wrapper around a Vec - a struct which holds the Vec and its max size, and implements insertion such that the data in the vec is always ordered, and values which are too small would get ignored (could have also used a BTreeSet, if N is large enough).

Anyway, I thought I'd use it as follows:

```
let mut q = SizedQueue(5);
<my iterator pipleline>.collect_into(&mut q);
```

but I was disappointed to discover that collect_into is unstable, and could potentially be dropped because it might be deemed unnecessary, the reason given is that it could be done differently.

My question is - how could it be done differently (other than me just implementing a Trait for Iterator with this functionality myself)?

Comment: The implementation of `your_iterator.collect_into(&mut q)` is just a call to `q.extend(your_iterator)`, so you could call that directly?

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks :) should have thought of that myself... It only make the code a bit uglier than collect_into, since I need to do it on a new line, and continue my pipeline in another new line - so 3 lines instead of 1 - but it's not too bad.

Comment: Not quite clear what you wnat, but it seems to me you can use `filter` or maybe just `take()` to get a new iterator for what you want, and then populate it as target type

Comment: @gftea if I understood well, the OP doesn't want the n first / last values, but the n biggest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect_into()` is just a convenient shortcut to calling [`Extend::extend()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend):

```rust
let mut q = SizedQueue(5);
q.extend(<my iterator pipleline>);
```

Of course, you need to implement [`Extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) for your type. A simple implementation may look like:

```rust
impl<T: PartialOrd> Extend<T> for SizedQueue<T> {
    fn extend<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(&mut self, iter: I) {
        for item in iter {
            self.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But if this is only for one use site where you call `extend()`, you may as well just inline it and loop and `push()`.